# Python troubles

Tags: python, numpy

I've been trying to throw together a python program that will align, crop and create an RGB image from HST and VLA .fits data. Unfortunately I've run into a bit of a problem with it continually opening a past file that does not exist in the folder and neither is it opening in the code itself. I've googled and googled and haven't found anything like it, so perhaps it's just common sense to most, but I can't figure it out. Here's the error message:

[image]

You can see at the top that the program I'm running has the filename *rgbhstvla.py*. I'm not sure what the error message means. Here's the python program as well:

```
import pyfits
import numpy as np
import pylab as py
import img_scale
from pyraf import iraf as ir

fits.open('3c68.fits', readonly)

j_img = pyfits.getdata('230UVIS.fits')
h_img = pyfits.getdata('230IR.fits')
k_img = pyfits.getdata('5GHZ.fits')

jmin,jmax = j_img.mean()+0.75*j_img.std(),j_img.mean()+5*j_img.std()
hmin,hmax = h_img.mean()+0.75*h_img.std(),h_img.mean()+5*h_img.std()
kmin,kmax = k_img.mean()+0.75*k_img.std(),k_img.mean()+5*k_img.std()

img = numpy.zeros((1024,1024,3))
img[:,:,0] = img_scale.asinh(j_img,scale_min=jmin,scale_max=jmax)
img[:,:,1] = img_scale.asinh(h_img,scale_min=hmin,scale_max=hmax)
img[:,:,2] = img_scale.asinh(k_img,scale_min=kmin,scale_max=kmax)

pylab.clf()
pylab.imshow(img)
pylab.show()
```

(I'm still working on the program since I'm new to python, tips here would be nice as well but they're mostly unnecessary as I'm sure I'll figure it out eventually).

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about Programming or image edition.

Comment: Try `#!/usr/bin/env python` in the first line. However, this belongs to Stackoverflow, not here.

Comment: There's a wizard's trick (don't tell anyone!) - it's **reading the error messages**. Applied wizardry gives rise to the idea that the IOError is risen because File '3c68.fits' does not exist (at least not where it should).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Python cannot find the file `3c68.fits`, which is expected to be in the current working directory, `C:\Users\Brandon\Desktop\Research`. Either make sure the file is in that directory, or provide an absolute path in your code.